# Checking time-stamps if they are from today in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, automation

I have a database with several tables. Each of these tables has a column 'created' which contains time-stamps of when that particular row was created in the database.

Now, I want to create a MySQL script that checks once every week if there is data coming into these tables. So, there should be data coming everyday. How do I create a MySQL script that allows me to do this for all the tables in the database?

**Note: Remember I want to do this for all the tables in the database with a single script. That's the main thing I want to know.**

Comment: I dont know of any solution to select from all tables at once, if they have unknown names. In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571894/select-from-all-tables/3571943#3571943) question the OP found a solution but it relies on the programming language he used. not on the MySQL script itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use this approach for a table called `call`, with a column of timestamp type called `systemdate`:

```
SELECT * FROM `call` WHERE DATE(`systemdate`) = DATE(NOW());
```

[mysql DATE() statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) gets the datepart of a datetime or timestamp field.

Sorry, just noticed that you want to check if atleast there is an entry for each of the days in the previous week.

you can use this query to check the prevous days individually:

yesterday:

```
SELECT * FROM `call` WHERE DATE(`systemdate`) = DATE(NOW()) - 1;
```

before yesterday:

```
SELECT * FROM `call` WHERE DATE(`systemdate`) = DATE(NOW()) - 2;
```

Or you can check the whole week at once:

```
SELECT * FROM `call` WHERE DATE(`systemdate`) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)  GROUP BY DATE(`systemdate`);
```

This will return one result for each day, so if you have 7 results you'll know at least an entry was made on each day.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also wanted to do this check on all the tables. Isn't there a way of doing this without having to create one of these that does for all the tables as all have that timestamp field?

Comment: If you know the name of the tables you can use the UNION. but, if you use union, how would you know if **each** table has an entry (ie, it could happen that only one of them was updated)? the best would be to do this in the programming language you're using to access mysql, you execute a SHOW TABLES mysql query, and for each table listed you run the script above.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table
where created between subdate(current_date, interval 7 day) and current_date;
```

Selecting datetimes up to `current_date` includes everything up to the start of "today" (ie "the previous midnight").